# Translate some string using google translator in winform in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, html-agility-pack, google-translate

I want to translate a string in my winform application.
i want to translate this from google translator.So my way is to use the scraping html methode using "HtmlAgilityPack".
Using the HTMLAgilityPack i want to show the translated string into a label in my winform.I googled but i failed to do that.How can i do that??? 
N:B:i dont want to use google tranlator api instead of this
I trid like this :

```
using HtmlAgilityPack; 
........
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load(
"http://translate.google.com/#en/bn/this%20is%20my%20string");
 var node = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
"//span[@class='short_text' and @id='result_box']");
 if (node != null)
    {
  foreach (var xx in node)
   {
    x = xx.InnerText;
    MessageBox.Show(x);
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this snippet](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/64790-c-translator-using-google-api/#axzz2IASiLc9n) about how to use Google API for translations.